# Can we modify IntelliSense VS Code suggestion that don't put a blank space before "=" when we insert parameter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

The problem is I would like a blank space after "=" sign in the image below but I can't find the setting to write in my settings.json for workspace. This problem is about Python libraries that are often written without putting a blank after parameter label.(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfvxW.jpg)

[vs code version installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHRTC.jpg)

Comment: have you seen the `Copy` button on your last image? That is not Intellisense it is the ItemCompletionProvider.

Comment: Thank for answer. I'm a beginner and I don't know how to edit ItemCompletionProvider. Could you suggest more?

Comment: read about creating VSC extensions, or create an issue for the Python extensions and request an option to add/remove the space